# Link/embed SVG in SVG so that the embedded document is interactive with scripting

Tags: javascript, svg, embed

How do I embed images in SVG with the same result as embedding in an `<object>` tag in HTML? When I use `<image>` the scripts in the embedded SVG won't execute, as if they were included as `<img>` in HTML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="900"
   height="750"
   id="svg3554"
   version="1.1">
  <g
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-302.36218)">
    <image
       y="386.53677"
       x="8.6410007"
       id="image4194"
       xlink:href="https://plotti.co/plottycocpu"
       height="252.65083"
       width="872.79382" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

And the image at https://plotti.co/plottycocpu is updating live

Comment: image/img disables scripting. There's no way round that. You need object as you are already aware.

Comment: https://longsonr.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/restrictions-on-svg-used-as-an-image/

Comment: AFAIK svg does not have `<object>` tag so that means that there is no way to use SVG linked inside SVG?

Comment: Sure there is: `<foreignObject><object></object></foreignObject>`